# How to cast media element in a uwp app to another device?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, mediaelement, miracast

I tried Advanced Miracasting sample(UWP) in git-hub for media element casting. I tried to cast media element from a windows 10 laptop to a Windows 10 PC.What i was expecting that my video will be played on PC. But actually whole screen is mirrored.Is there any way to cast my video or media(only).Do i need to change any settings?

Comment: You mean that pass the media stream to Windows 10 Pc from your laptop with Miracast, am I right?

Comment: Yes @NicoZhu-MSFT